# Comparing two String ArrayLists and get same value in console

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 2 below string array list.

```
ArrayList<String> sourceArray = [bg, zh_cn, cs, da, en_us];
ArrayList<String> targetArray = [bg, pt, ru, sg, da, en_us];
```

I want to write the code in Java, where I will compare this two `ArrayList` get the same value in output, like below.

If `sourceArray` is equal to `targetArray` then it should print below:

```
System.out.println("bg is similar in both array");
```

My output should be as below:

```
bg is similar in both array
da is similar in both array
en_us is similar in both array
```

Comment: arrays and `ArrayList`s are very different things. I suggest you research your prompt thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that they are ArrayList of String.

```
ArrayList<String> sourceArray=...;
ArrayList<String> targetArray=...;
```

if the position is not relevant:

```
for(String s : sourceArray) {
    if(targetArray.contains(s)) {
        System.out.println(s.concat(" is similar in both array"));
    }
}
```

else (obviously assuming they have the same size):

```
for(int i=0; i<targetArray.size(); i++) {
    if(sourceArray.get(i).equals(targetArray.get(i))) {
        System.out.println(sourceArray.get(i).concat(" is similar in both array"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sourceArray.retainAll(targetArray);
// sourceArray now only contains those similar items
// print them
sourceArray.forEach(string -> System.out.println(string + " is similar in both arrays"));
```

If you don't want to alter sourceArray, then just create a temporary ArrayList to hold the items instead.